# Javascript: body.append(content) is not rendered as html

Tags: javascript, html, documentfragment

I am building a little piece of html document using javascript templates. `const button` in the code below is my template. As you can see I replace some content using replace. `const button` become `<button>label</button>` and that's fine.

```
const button = `<button>{try}</button>`;
const newButton = button.replace('{try}', 'label');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
```

Now I want to append my bew button inside body tag.

```
body.append(newButton);
```

It works BUT when I refresh browser I see "`<button>label</button>`" but I want the rendered version of this html and now I cant see a button but a string `<button>...`. How can I render this button?

Comment: You can also access body via `document.body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)?

```js
const button = `<button>{try}</button>`;
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, button.replace('{try}', 'label'));
```